# nested compound interest using ruby

Tags: ruby

```
p "barakas nested compound interest"

def baraka_interest(name,h,r,t,r2,r3,f)

    while  1..t do
     a = h * (1 + r)
     i = h * r  # interest on first month
     k = i*(1 + r2) # first 100 %
     m = 0.5 * k    # half of 100% profit
     v = m*(1 + r3)   # interest on 1000% profit
     z = a + m + v 
     a = z 

    end
    x = t.to_s
    y = a.to_s

  "After #{x} months #{name} will have #{y} dollars!"

end

p baraka_interest("baraka",1000,0.1,24,1,10,1)
```

hello i am trying to calculate what the result amount will be for value compounded on monthly basis at 10% , but the profit after each month is also compounded at 100% (k) , and half of the profit from the 1000%(), the above calculation is done for 24 months or 2 yrs

Comment: That `while` loop will never finish.

Comment: hello sergio , how can i get the solution for that

Comment: The key to not having infinite loops is to exit them when you reach your stop condition. I am not familiar with the problem you're trying to solve, so I have no idea what the stop condition would be and also if you picked the right loop or not.

Comment: Standard compound interest would be `amount = principal * (1 + rate/periods_in_a_year) **(periods_in_a_year*years)` I believe. Are you sure your math is accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this code works as you expectid (i mean the math).

But this is valid code for you

```
def baraka_interest(name, h, r, t, r2, r3, f)
  a = 0
  1.upto(t) do
    a += h * (1 + r)
    i = h * r # interest on first month
    k = i*(1 + r2) # first 100 %
    m = 0.5 * k # half of 100% profit
    v = m*(1 + r3) # interest on 1000% profit
    z = a + m + v
    a = z
  end
  x = t.to_s
  y = a.to_s

  "After #{x} months #{name} will have #{y} dollars!"
end

p "barakas nested compound interest"
p baraka_interest("baraka", 1000, 0.1, 24, 1, 10, 1)
# => "After 24 months baraka will have 55200.0 dollars!"
```

Comment: this code works but testing it with two months gives a wrong answer

Comment: @BarakaLetara I dont rly know what Math is behind this.

Comment: its just compound interest but think that the interest generated monthly is also compounded at higher rates and then added to the principal. redusing risk